# Como criar uma Lista e SubLista?

Tags: android, listview

Estou querendo popular uma uma **ListView** com base em duas tabelas, uma chamada categoria e a outra subcategoria, e gostaria de que ficasse mais ou menos assim:

[image: Exemplo da tela]

Quando eu digitasse um nome pra Categoria no **EditText** e clicasse no botão Adicionar, adicionasse na tabela categoria e já aparecesse dinamicamente como um item da tabela, e quando eu clicasse no botão pra adicionar uma subcategoria abrisse um *dialog* pra eu inserir um nome de SubCategoria e então, quando clicasse num botão pra adicionar, inserisse na tabela subcategoria e dinamicamente aparecesse abaixo da categoria relacionada.

onCreate da CategoriaListActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_categoria_list);


    CategoriaDAO categoria = new CategoriaDAO(this);
    List<Categoria> list = categoria.getLista();
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(new CategoriaAdapter(this, list, listView));



}
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54627/discussion-on-question-by-allan-chrystian-como-criar-uma-lista-e-sublista)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe aqui:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SubListaExemplo{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
// Os elementos vão aqui ser add
    arrayList.add("1");
    arrayList.add("2");
    arrayList.add("3");
    arrayList.add("4");
    arrayList.add("5");

//Criando a sublista:
    List lst = arrayList.subList(1,3);


//display elements of sub list.
System.out.println("Sub list contains : ");
for(int i=0; i< lst.size() ; i++)
  System.out.println(lst.get(i));
```

Ou, como eu usei no meu projeto, você usa o tag ListView no xml assim e já aparecer em sub itens:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ArrayList serve pro banco também?